# Run next command in a newly created terminal

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt

I would like to run one command that runs three new commands, in three separate terminal windows. However, I do not want to reference three separate batch files.

I realise that I can run `start` to open a new terminal window, and that I can run `start file.bat` to open a window and run command(s) which are stored within that batch file. However, I would like to keep everything in the same file.

So rather than:

```
start file-1.bat
start file-2.bat
start file-3.bat
```

I would like to do:

```
start [code to run in new window]
start [code to run in new window]
start [code to run in new window]
```

If I chain commands with `&&` a new terminal is opened but the next command is ran in the original window.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is when you use some commandline parameters to your own batch file and add some goto labels where you want your split code to be.

Example "myfile.bat":

```
@echo off
set thisfile=%~0
echo Unquoted Param1=%~1

if "%~1" == "jump1" goto jump1
if "%~1" == "jump2" goto jump2
if "%~1" == "jump3" goto jump3

start "Title1" "%thisfile%" "jump1"
start "Title2" "%thisfile%" "jump2"
start "Title3" "%thisfile%" "jump3"

:jump1
echo First new console window executes this
pause
goto eof

:jump2
echo Second new console window executes this
pause
goto eof

:jump3
echo Third new console window executes this
pause
goto eof

:eof
```

Maybe you need to fiddle around with the `start` command a bit. See `start /?` for the syntax and especially for the `/D` parameter which sets the directory to execute the command in. If needed, separate path and filename with `%~dp0` for drive and path only and `%~nx0` for the filename with extension only.
If you do not want a title, then you might want to specify `""` still or `start` might interpret the path to the `myfile.bat` as title and quits with an error message because the syntax is not matched.
If I got you wrong and the three terminals just should execute the same code, which you only wanted to be inside your file, than just remove the "jump2" and "jump3" sections and call every terminal with a "jump1" parameter (which you could rename of course).

GL, HF :)